# Avoiding mutable booleans indicating state

Tags: f#

Suppose that before you enter a long running process, you have to perform some pre-start checks.

Suppose also that once these checks are satisfied you do not need to do the checks again (perhaps there are many of these checks and are also relatively expensive to perform).

How can state be avoided here?

More generally, in Python, you could have something like a generator or coroutine which could hold these checks and state. Is there a nice F-sharpy way of getting rid of the mutable booleans to indicate skipping each of the satisfied checks?

```
let r = new System.Random()

let someCondition1 () = 
    r.Next() % 523452321 = 0 

let someCondition2 () = 
    r.Next() % 243142321 = 0 

let mutable conditionCheck1 = false
let mutable conditionCheck2 = false
let rec conditionChecks () =

    match conditionCheck1 with
    | true -> ()
    | false -> match someCondition1 () with
               | false -> conditionChecks ()
               | true  -> conditionCheck1 <- true // never check again

    match conditionCheck2 with
    | true -> ()
    | false -> match someCondition2 () with
               | false -> conditionChecks ()
               | true  -> conditionCheck2 <- true // never check again

let rec eventLoop () =
    eventLoop ()

conditionChecks ()
eventLoop ()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that your `conditionChecks` function recurses after every `false` value. It looks to me like you're trying to write the following algorithm:

1. Write a function for each condition to be checked.
2. Wait for all the conditions to become true. (Keep re-checking any condition that was false).
3. Proceed with the event loop.

It seems to me that having each condition check be some sort of `async` expression would be a good solution here. The `async` would keep running until the condition becomes true, then finish and return a `true` value. You'd then collect the asyncs in a list, and run the whole list of asyncs synchronously. Bonus: if the conditions are such that their checks can be performed in parallel, this will save you time.

```
let r = new System.Random()

let rec someCondition1 () =
    async {
        // if r.Next() % 523452321 = 0 then
        printfn "Checking condition 1"
        if r.Next() % 52 = 0 then  // So our output is shorter
            return true
        else
            return! someCondition1 ()
    }

let rec someCondition2 () = 
    async {
        // if r.Next() % 243142321 = 0 then
        printfn "Checking condition 2"
        if r.Next() % 24 = 0 then  // So our output is shorter
            return true
        else
            return! someCondition2 ()
    }

let allConditions = [
    someCondition1 ()
    someCondition2 ()
]

let rec eventLoop () =
    printfn "Event loop runs now"
    // eventLoop ()  // Disabled so our test run will not infiloop

let ready = allConditions |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
if Array.reduce (&&) ready then
    eventLoop()
else
    printfn "Some conditions returned false somehow"
```

Running this for me produced varied results, of course, but they usually looked something like this:

```
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 2
Checking condition 2
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 2
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 2
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Checking condition 1
Event loop runs now
```

As you can see, condition 2 managed to return `true` on its fourth attempt, and stopped -- while condition 1 took about twenty-five tries before it got a `true` result. But once all the results were `true`, the event loop ran.

By the way, the way I wrote this also allows for an "abort" in the condition checks. If any condition check can determine that it will *never* be satisfiable, it could return `false`, in which case the event loop will not run. So:

```
let condition1CanNeverBeTrue () =
    r.Next() % 123456789 = 0

let rec someCondition1 () =
    async {
        if r.Next() % 523452321 = 0 then
            return true
        else
            if condition1CanNeverBeTrue() then
                return false
            else
                return! someCondition1 ()
    }
```

You may not need this extra feature, but it might come in handy.

Also, if you can't run the conditions in parallel but they MUST run sequentially, then replace the `let ready = ...` line with:

```
let ready = allConditions |> List.map Async.RunSynchronously
```

and, of course, use `List.reduce` instead of `Array.reduce` at the end.

Comment: Note the use of both `return` and `return!` in the async expressions. `return` takes the value given and wraps it in an `Async<'T>` (here, that's an `Async<bool>`. Whereas `return!` wants an `Async<'T>` and just passes it on as-is. Thus, `return! someCondition1 ()` ends up being a tail call, and this code will never exhaust the stack.

Comment: Also note that I actually *call* the `someCondition` functions when I build the `allConditions` list. That's because their signature is `unit -> Async<bool>`. Calling them doesn't actually run the async, it just creates the `Async<bool>` object, which won't run until it's passed into `Async.RunSynchronously` (or `Async.Start` or one of the other methods in the `Async` module that tell you that they actually *run* the asynchronous computation).

Comment: The `r.Next()` call is not thread-safe; if you want to avoid synchronization, each condition needs to own its own `Random`.

Comment: Good point, though I'm pretty sure the random numbers are just for illustration's sake and that the actual code uses different conditions.

Comment: @ildjarn `MathNet.Numerics.Random` has thread-safe `Random` if necessary but I don't think it's a vital part of the Q (I don't know though).

Comment: rmunn's answer is impressive. For simple stuff I think the mutable flag can be off-loaded into a class or a closure to hold the state. That is, I don't see that much harm in having a mutable there. Won't be the end of the world (veiled Gjallarhorn reference... :)

Comment: The `async` ceremony could even go into it's own function, taking the actual check as a parameter.

Comment: In fact, there is an issue with thread safety since I'm using zmq sockets to subscribe to data. This answer is so great that i didn't really want to pollute it with that issue. I will post another question with the thread safety issue incorporated.

Comment: @professorbigglesworth - If you've got messages that need to be passed around between various async operations, the `MailboxProcessor` class is well worth looking into. Google it and read anything you can find on the subject -- and http://www.fssnip.net/7P5 might be useful to you, depending on what exactly you're doing with ZMQ.

Comment: @professorbigglesworth - And see also https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/MailboxProcessor for a basic introduction.

Comment: @rmunn This is extremely helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think a lazy value would work nicely here.

You can have the lazy value store the result of a function and then it does the caching for you.